# Disable double tap magnifying glass in Safari iOS

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility, mobile-safari

I'm making a web browser game and I found out that double tapping in Safari iOS brings up this magnifying glass feature:

[image: Bubble]

I want to disable it, but can't manage to find out how. I tried `user-select: none` (actually `-webkit-user-select: none` for Safari), `touch-action: none` and a wide variety of `event.preventDefault()`.

There are topics covering how to hide it for long press (and here `-webkit-user-select: none` works), and other topics how to disable double tap zoom, but I haven't found a way to hide this magnifying glass for double tap gesture.

Can it even be done?

Comment: Double tapping with **3 fingers** invokes the zoom accessibility feature. A normal single finger double tap does not do that. (If VoiceOver were on, then a single finger double tap would active the element, such as check a checkbox or select a button.) You didn't specify in your question how many fingers you were using with the double tap gesture. If you are using 3 fingers, then you absolutely do **not** want to disable that feature. The user has enabled the zoom feature for a reason - so they can magnify the screen and read it.

Comment: @slugolicious interesting, because on my iPhone it does that with one finger and I have never changed any Accessibility settings.

Comment: That's odd. There must be something different set. I'm on iOS 16.3.1.  If you go to the Safari app and open any URL, say [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/), then you double tap with a single finger on any piece of text (don't double tap on a link), you get the magnifying glass?

Comment: @slugolicious yes, I do. Even when I do that on an empty space. I double tap and hold, i.e. tap-release-tap-hold.

Comment: *"I double tap and **hold**"*. There's the missing information! You didn't say you **held** your finger down in the gesture. Just that you double tapped. The "magnifier" you see is not really a magnifier. It's not making anything bigger. It's for selecting text. So the double tap (single finger) starts a selection (to mark text) and if you hold that tap and start dragging left, right, or up, the little "bubble" displays above your finger to help you see where you are marking text since the actual mark is below your fingertip, obscuring what you can see. If you drag down, the bubble disappears.

Comment: Now that that is straightened out, back to your original question. I'm not aware of a way to turn that off, sorry. I suppose if Safari didn't think there was any text to mark under your finger, maybe it wouldn't display the bubble?

Comment: @slugolicious sorry, I thought it was a known gesture. It doesn't seem to keep track of whether there is anything to select though, as it even works on `about:blank` page.

Comment: *"sorry, I thought it was a known gesture"*.  It **is** a known gesture but is not the one you were asking about. You may want to update your question to say "double tap and hold" instead of just "double tap" (which is its own gesture).

Answer (score 3):

If your game is an embedded `WkWebView` there is a property in your configuration of the web view that can disable interactive text. This turns off the ability to select, double-top and drag to enlarge text via the magnifying glass. But, it also changes the behavior *all* text interaction. So, perhaps it's best to use with caution.

```swift
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
let view = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
view.configuration.preferences.isTextInteractionEnabled = false
```

If it's a website available through Mobile Safari, then you can intercept event propagation for specific elements through the `touchend` and `touchcancel` event. Though, this can also have other unintended effects basically that the events won't bubble up to their parents for `click`s or that the chain of events won't complete, like the same element's `click` event.

```js
const eventParams = { passive: false };
document.body.addEventListener('touchcancel', ignore, eventParams);
document.body.addEventListener('touchend', ignore, eventParams);

function ignore(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

I haven't found a way *only* in CSS to disable this.

Comment: For the JavaScript side of the solution, here is another implementation I used in a similar way. It's more specific because it's trying to intercept the **second** tap in the Mobile Safari user flow: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/iphone-how-to-remove-text-selection-magnifier/47812/11

Comment: It's a website. It looks like `touchend` is enough, I'll need to think how to incorporate it without affecting useful default browser behavior.

Comment: I also commented on this thread for a similar intercept, but specifically on the `touchstart` of a double tap, which on iOS is the trigger for the magnifying glass: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/iphone-how-to-remove-text-selection-magnifier/47812/11

Comment: you saved my life, since you gave the only right answer which comes from `touchEnd`

Answer (score 0):

Example of how I solved this problem for Safari:

```js
main();
canvas.addEventListener("touchend", e => game(e));
canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", e => game(e));
canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", e => game(e));

document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => e.preventDefault(), { passive: false });
```

All you normally have to do is add this line of code :

```js
document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => e.preventDefault(), { passive: false });
```

Oh also if you add `e.preventDefault()` in the function `game(e)` (or other for you) is not working for me